# Error 11009: property 'update date' is not mapped

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

When I create a table in SQL Server and then I want to update my data model from database in Visual Studio, I get this error:

> error 11009 : property 'update date' is not mapped

and

> error 3004 : problem in mapping fragments starting at line 869: no mapping specified for properties customer.updatedate in set customers.
>   an entity with key(pk) will not round-trip when :
>   Entity is type [stockModel.Customer]

Help me please

Answer (score 0):

You must map the property from database to your data access layer using Entity Framework(Object Relational Mapping) concept and if you are using Data transfer object layer and Data access layer both then you can map using Automapper.